# Users with accounts on all sites -- no labels

Tags: feature-request

Apologies if I'm being completely out of line here by pointing out what I perceive to be small but not intractable problems. I'm on three medications right now, and one of them is booze.

When you're looking at the profile of a user who has accounts on every SO network, it isn't immediately obvious which box is for what site. The only differentiator seems to be the tiny icon to the left of the user's name.

Wouldn't it make a lot more sense to have a textual label for each box?

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/flair-should-be-more-distinctive-about-site-name

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. As I understand it, flair can be displayed on sites other than the SO network. My issue is with how the SO network displays user's affiliations across the network VIA THE USE OF flair. It is a subtle but important distinction. For a drunk.

Comment: +1 for drunk typing on Meta!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it would.

What else can I say?

Comment: You obviously get the checkmark... although I'm left with the unstatisfactory feeling that I've sidestepped the purpose of these questions.

Comment: Except that I've uncheckked it because I'm not sure how the checkmarking interacts with the "feature-request" aspect of the question.

Comment: Not at all. But I didn't answer to get any checkmarks here.

Comment: That was a passive aggressive checkmark... or was it?

Answer (score 2):

I like it the way it is. Maybe your medicine is limiting your eye-sight ;)

Workaround: Hover over the link to the site and read the status bar of your browser.

Comment: I think I've found my mSO archnemesis

Comment: You can make friends fast here on MSO :)

Comment: Cheers to that :-D

Comment: German. It's no secret that I try to improve my English. What's the problem?

Comment: No no problem I was just curious (it was mentioned in one of your top rated comments). I thought it might have been rude which is why I deleted my comment. I actually wouldn't have been able to tell you weren't a native speaker otherwise.

Comment: Good to read that I'm getting better :)